# Multiple Themes for your product - why should you offer them?

Tags: usability, customisation

When you're selling a product, do you think it's important to offer the users various themes (in order for them to choose the one they like most or to customize it to their brand)?

What are the advantages of having this option? Should I just offer one theme? My question is related to website makers, like WordPress and Blogspot....If I wanted to make a webpage creator, is offering several themes really that important?

Answer (score 2):

Customization in consumer products has always been targeted at "making it yours". We're all unique so even if we all have an iPhone and we're all on Facebook, we like that unicity to shine through somewhere. Some services used to overdo that (*ahem* myspace *ahem*). Facebook and Twitter on the other hand have a nice balance of offering customization, allowing you to show your personality on your profile page, while keeping the usability and look & feel of the service in tact.

This is true as well for websites. If you're going to create a website for a business, they'll definitely feel they're unique and they are going to want it to look like it's theirs. And they're going to want to feel like they had a say in how it looks.

So picking a theme is never going to be sufficient. Even if there are a hundred themes, any theme you choose a customer will want to customize at some level.

What options you should offer depends on many factors. For instance, you could offer only one or two themes that can be further customized with images and colors. Just explain the limitations get you the best set of features for the lowest price and that further customization would be more expensive. And at the other end of the spectrum you could do without themes at all and build everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple themes for designers who would design their websites using WordPress are absolutely a requirement as the designer needs freedom of expression and variety to choose from or they wouldn't feel they have "designed". Variety is a sense of change, interest and adventure that we all ****need**** in order to feel alive. This is the same need which you fulfill by going to a shop with 1000 styles and colors of shoes and not the one that only had one style.

But variety must be within certain limits or it starts to bog us down. Have a look at [Barry Schwartz: The paradox of choice](http://www.ted.com/talks/barry_schwartz_on_the_paradox_of_choice.html) who advocates why Choices are bad but also look at [Malcolm Gladwell: Choice, happiness and spaghetti sauce](http://www.ted.com/talks/malcolm_gladwell_on_spaghetti_sauce.html).

Concluding: Your designers need freedom and variety to choose from. You are in ART oriented business where 16 million colors are not just enough. Good luck.